# Parse Cloud Code - How to add object from another class to user

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

My application displays data to my users via the Parse.com. I am using their iOS sdk with their cloud code. I am required to use cloud code to add an object to my user. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
[PFCloud callFuction:@"addObjectToUser" withParameters:params];
```

And my parameters would be the userID and the the object ID of the object I want associated with that user ID.

How would I achieve this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change anything on a user object in parse (without being changed by the user themselves) it must be done through cloud code and by using the `useMasterKey()`. Assuming that you have set up your `params` like this:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{userID: @"12345", objectID: @"67890"};
```

You can save objects to a user with the master key like this:

```
//Add Object To User's "objectsAddedToUser" array
Parse.Cloud.define("addObjectToUser", function(request, response) {

    // (1)
    var userID = request.params.userID;
    var objectID = request.params.objectID;

    // (2)
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("userID", userID);
    query.first().then(function (user) {

        // (3)
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

        // (4)
        user.add("objectsAddedToUser", objectID);

        // (5)
        user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
        }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
        });


    }, function (error) {

        response.error(error);

    });

});
```

**(1)** Get the parameters that you passed in.

**(2)** Query the database and retrieve the user that needs to be updated.

**(3) IMPORTANT** Use the master key to unlock privileges.

**(4)** Add the `objectID` to the user.

**(5)** Save to Parse.

Answer (score 1):

Adding cloud function is explain in detail [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code), there is an example as well which explain how you can write java-script function to manipulate or add data.